# button event does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

UPDATE:
This is what ultimately worked:

```
if (lbAuthorList.SelectedItem != null)
      {
            if (lblAuthorName.Text.Equals("Unknown", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
         {
```

the rest of the code stays the same.

Thank you to everyone who helped me with their suggestions.

I am trying to fire off an event if the value of my label is "Unknown".

Library users select the author's name from a list box.  If the name of the author is "unknown". the label is changed to the value selected - which is "unknown" if selected, then it supposed to run a stored procedure.  Problem is - nothing is happening when the selected value from the listbox is "unknown".  Can anyone tell me why and how to fix this?
Below is my code and code behind:

```
protected void btnAddAuthors_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      lblAuthorName.Text = lbAuthorList.SelectedItem.ToString(); 

    if (lblAuthorName.Text == "Unknown")
   {


      sqlInsertUnknownInfo.InsertParameters.Clear();
      sqlInsertUnknownInfo.InsertParameters.Add("RequestID", DbType.Int32,     Request.QueryString["Requestid"]);
       sqlInsertUnknownInfo.InsertParameters.Add("AuthorID", DbType.Int32,    AuthorID.ToString());
         }

 protected void authorList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblAuthorName.Text= lbAuthorList.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
 }

<asp:Label id="lblAuthorName" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium"  OnDataBinding= "AuthorList_SelectedIndexChanged"/><br /> <br />    


<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="lbAuthorList" 
   style="float:left;" DataSourceID="Authors" 
   DataTextField="DisplayName" DataValueField="AuthorName" 
   onselectedindexchanged="AuthorList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
   AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
</asp:DropDownList>   



 <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sqlInsertAuthors" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:rainerCounty %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:rainerCounty.ProviderName %>" 
SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="addAuthors" >
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Requestid" Type="Int32" QueryStringField="id" />
     <asp:ProfileParameter Name="AuthorID" Type="Int32" PropertyName="AuthorID" />  
 </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: It's a little unclear in your question. You have a button that has to be pressed for that logic to execute right? Or are you wanting it on the selection change of the DropDownList? And have you put a breakpoint in the btnAddAuthors_Click method to see what the value of lbAuthorList.SelectedItem.ToString() is?

Comment: Yes - the button has to be pressed for the logic to execute.  I did put a breakpoint in the method but nothing was displayed and I can not understand why nothing is being passed when I can see the value of the label on the page.

Comment: It appears that your DropDownList has a datasource called Authors which appears to be an object with properties of DisplayName and AuthorName. In your _Click method try casting .SelectedItem to that object type and getting the value of .AuthorName instead of calling .ToString on SelectedItem. That doesn't explain why the Label works though.

Comment: I changed this line if (lblAuthorName.Text == "Unknown") to this: if (lbAuthorList.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Unknown") and it skipped over the condition. Is this how you meant me to make this change?

Comment: What is the Authors object defined as in the code in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling .ToString() on SelectedItem. SelectedItem is not the string you see in the drop down list. Instead it's the class that has properties of DisplayName and AuthorName.

[DropDownList SelectedItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I'm not sure if you've overridden the ToString method for whatever class is used to store author information (I used YourAuthorClass in my example), but this could be the source of the problem. I believe the following code is what you need.

```
if (lbAuthorList.SelectedItem != null)
{
    if (typeof(YourAuthorClass) == lbAuthorList.SelectedItem.GetType())
    {
        YourAuthorClass currentSelection = (YourAuthorClass)lbAuthorList.SelectedItem;
        if (currentSelection.AuthorName == "Unknown")
        {
            sqlInsertUnknownInfo.InsertParameters.Clear();
            sqlInsertUnknownInfo.InsertParameters.Add("RequestID", DbType.Int32,     Request.QueryString["Requestid"]);
            sqlInsertUnknownInfo.InsertParameters.Add("AuthorID", DbType.Int32,    AuthorID.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fodderzone - sorry about the delay in answering.  Had a network router issue and had to work on it.  I used the above.  The only problem I had was with this line:  YourAuthorClass currentSelection = (YourAuthorClass)lbAuthorList.SelectedItem;
 The lbAuthorList gives me an error that the class doesn’t contain a definition for lbAuthorList.  I looked at my Author class and used every variable there and still got the error.

Comment: I now know that even though the value of my selected author is displaying on the page's label, when I try an d pass it to the event what is actually being passed is "Make Author Selection" - the first value of the dropdown list - not the selected value.   How is that happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
protected void btnAddAuthors_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedAuthorIndex = lbAuthorList.SelectedIndex; 
    var selectedAuthorValue = lbAuthorList.SelectedValue; 
    if (selectedAuthorIndex != 0 && selectedAuthorValue == "Unknown")
    {
        lblAuthorName.Text = selectedAuthorValue; 
        //....
    }
}
```